# Why is response from recaptcha is null?

Tags: php, recaptcha

PHP

```
$ch = curl_init();
$options = [
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify',
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => [
        'secret' => 'key',
        'response' => $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'],
    ],
];

curl_setopt_array($ch,$options);

$out = curl_exec($ch) ;
$a = json_decode($out);
var_dump($a);
```

when i fill recaptcha it return only null in this file. which is best options through this api or download recaptcha package .

Comment: remove the last comma from 'response' => $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'] , and the comma closing CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS

Comment: @ZiTAL  still  giving null

Comment: @ZiTAL Why? Trailing commas in arrays have been explicitly supported for years (if not forever). And if they wouldn't they'd just trigger a parse error.

Comment: You have to use `curl_getinfo()` and `curl_error()` to obtain diagnostic information.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález  error show "Could not resolve host: www.google.com"

Comment: Your server does not have properly configured internet access (more specifically, DNS resolution) or something prevents PHP from using it.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález    i am using xampp for local server. can you tell me where can be that error ?

Comment: Xampp is a third-party bundle and I'm not familiar with it. But I think you should first determine your operating system (Windows? Linux?) and look for the problem outside PHP (firewall, SELinux, etc.)

Comment: before var_dump decoded json, first var_dump the response $out var